# Get table from iframe or all content from 1st iframe

Tags: vba, web-scraping

With below code I'm trying to get table data which is located in `iframe` having name `displayFrame`. Any help is appreciated.
But getting below error while accessing `innertext`:

```
Run-time error 438:
Object doesn't support this property or method
```

Code:

```
Sub GetTableFromIframe()

 Dim Ie As New InternetExplorer
 Dim WebURL
 Dim Docx As HTMLDocument
 Dim productDesc As Object

 Ie.Visible = True

    WebURL = "https://example.com"
     Ie.Navigate2 WebURL
     Do Until Ie.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE
     DoEvents
     Loop
     Set Docx = Ie.document

    Do Until Not productDesc Is Nothing
    Set productDesc = Docx.Window.Frames("displayFrame").contentWindow ' gtetting same error here
    Sleep 1000
    Loop

     productDesc = Docx.Window.frames("displayFrame").contentWindow.document.getElementsByClassName("Table")(0).innerText
   
    Debug.Print productDesc

End Sub
```

Another macro gets other error, added in comment:

```
Sub GetIframeContent()

Dim objIE As Object
Set objIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
Dim productDesc As Object

objIE.Visible = True
objIE.navigate "https://webtac.industrysoftware.automation.siemens"

While objIE.readyState <> 4
        DoEvents
Wend

Open "d:\temp\test.log" For Output As #3
MsgBox objIE.document.getElementsByTagName("iframe")(0).contentDocument.getElementsByTagName("body")(0).innerText ' gets error Object variable or with block variable not set
'Write #3, objIE.document.getElementsByTagName("iframe")(0).contentDocument.getElementsByClassName("under")(0).innerHTML
Write #3, productDesc
Close #3

Set objIE = Nothing
End Sub
```

Parent page:
[image]
Iframe page:
[image]

Comment: Can you share the URL or at least the whole HTML contents?

Comment: className seems to be "under" and not "table" ?  "Table" is the`tagName`.  You're doing too much in that one line to easily troubleshoot - breaking it out into more lines with some intermediate variables would help find exactly where the problem is.

Comment: Yes, with `tageName` also it doesn't work.

Comment: Updated the code images since url won't work in public.

Comment: Any help? Can I get all content from 1st iframe?

Comment: Like I suggested - break it down and see where it fails.  Can you access the frame?  Can you access the document in the frame?  Can you access any specific elements in that document?  Remember just because the frameset is loaded, it doesn't mean the frames' *contents* have finished loading, so try putting a wait to ensure all content is complete before you try to access anything.

Comment: Added `Do Until` loop but it fails in its 1st line with error. Updated code. Error appears after page has finished loading and all content is displayed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got it. I was searching for `ifarme` instead of `frame`. Further I located `table` with `classname` and extracted data to sheet.

```
Sub Web_Table_Option_Two() ''' Find table with class name in 1st frame on page and extract table data
Dim HTMLDoc As New HTMLDocument
Dim objTable As Object
Dim lRow As Long
Dim lngTable As Long
Dim lngRow As Long
Dim lngCol As Long
Dim ActRw As Long
Dim objIE As InternetExplorer
Set objIE = New InternetExplorer
'objIE.navigate "https://webtac.industrysoftware.automation.siemens"
objIE.navigate "https://webtac.industrysoftware.automation.siemens.com"

Do Until objIE.readyState = 4 And Not objIE.Busy
DoEvents
Loop


Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:03")) 'wait for java script to load
HTMLDoc.body.innerHTML = objIE.document.getElementsByTagName("frame")(0).contentDocument.getElementsByClassName("under")(0).innerHTML
With HTMLDoc.body
Set objTable = .getElementsByTagName("table")
For lngTable = 0 To objTable.Length - 1
    For lngRow = 0 To objTable(lngTable).Rows.Length - 1
        For lngCol = 0 To objTable(lngTable).Rows(lngRow).Cells.Length - 1
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(ActRw + lngRow + 1, lngCol + 1) = objTable(lngTable).Rows(lngRow).Cells(lngCol).innerText
        Next lngCol
    Next lngRow
    ActRw = ActRw + objTable(lngTable).Rows.Length + 1
Next lngTable
End With
objIE.Quit

End Sub
```